# bash: BASH_XTRACEFD: 5: invalid value for trace file descriptor

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I want to do the same thing as [shell - Suppress the bash execution trace (set -x) from the outside of the script - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352089/suppress-the-bash-execution-trace-set-x-from-the-outside-of-the-script)'s one.

When I doing Bash debugging, sometimes a command (`spinner 'Now loading... ' &`) occurred and the command make debugging output dirty because the command is using `while` loop so a lot of amount of output there is.

In this case, I want to suppress the output of the command by something like `spinner 'Now loading... ' 5>/dev/null &`.

I searched how to do it and I found solution that is `BASH_XTRACEFD`.

But I try to define the variable in a command line, there is a error occurred as following.

```
$ export BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
bash: BASH_XTRACEFD: 5: invalid value for trace file descriptor
```

I guess the reason why the error occurred is file descriptor is closed or something wrong. but I have no idea what have to do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you linked to shows the correct way of doing it, which is in a single line before creating a new shell by running a script.

Your problem is that your currently doing this in a interactive shell which does not have a file descriptor 5. You can fix the problem by replacing your shell and creating that file descriptor beforehand, if you just want to discard all of set -x, then you can use

`exec 5>
export BASH_XTRACEFD=5`

That should take care of the problem you demonstrated, however I feel like you're just trying to redirect stderr, so instead do

```
--> ls -l foo
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
root@mybox[/tmp] Wed Jul 03 <11:17:46>
--> ls -l foo 2>/dev/null # Notice the 2>/dev/null after the command
root@mybox [/tmp] Wed Jul 03 <11:17:50>
```

And that will supress the spinner in case it's writing to stderr.